# Delegating the creation of data structures

Tags: rust

I’m very new to Rust. While trying out small things, I have written the following code. It simply scans files (given as arguments) for a specific string (“Started “) and prints out the matching lines:

```
use std::os;
use std::io::BufferedReader;
use std::io::File;

fn main() {
    for target in os::args().iter() {
        scan_file(target);
    }
}

fn scan_file(path_str: &String) {
    let path = Path::new(path_str.as_bytes());
    let file = File::open(&path);
    let mut reader = BufferedReader::new(file);

    for line in reader.lines() {
        match line {
            Ok(s) => {
                if s.as_slice().contains("Started ") {
                    print!("{}", s);
                }
            }
            Err(_) => return,
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: how can I refactor the function `scan_file` so that it looks something like this (or similar enough)?:

```
fn scan_file(path_str: &String) {
    for line in each_line_in_file_with_path(path_str) {
        match line {
            Ok(s) => {
                if s.as_slice().contains("Started ") {
                    print!("{}", s);
                }
            }
            Err(_) => return,
        }
    }
}
```

In this new version of the function, the three variable declarations are gone. Instead, the function `each_line_in_file_with_path` is expected to handle all the “turn a path into lines”, returning an iterator.

I’ve tried a number of things unsuccessfully, always due to variables going out of scope too early for my needs. I understand the problems I have (I think), but can’t find anywhere a good explanation of how this should be handled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to implement a working `each_line_in_file_with_path` function — at least, not without adding some overhead and unsafe code.

Let's look at the values involved and their types. First is `path`, of type `Path` (either [`posix::Path`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/posix/struct.Path.html) or [`windows::Path`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/windows/struct.Path.html)). The constructors for these types receive a [`BytesContainer`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/trait.BytesContainer.html) by value, therefore they take ownership of it. No issues here.

Next is `file`, of type `IoResult<File>`. [`File::open()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/fs/struct.File.html#method.open) clones the path it receives, so again, no issues here.

Next is `reader`, of type `BufferedReader<IoResult<File>>`. Just like `Path`, the constructor for `BufferedReader` takes its argument by value and takes ownership of it.

The problem is with `reader.lines()`. This value is of type `Lines<'r, T: 'r>`. As the type signature suggests, this struct contains a borrowed reference. The signature of [`lines`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufferPrelude.html#tymethod.lines) shows the relationship between the loaner and the borrower:

```
fn lines<'r>(&'r mut self) -> Lines<'r, Self>
```

How do we define `each_line_in_file_with_path` now? `each_line_in_file_with_path` cannot return a `Lines` directly. You probably tried writing the function like this:

```
fn each_line_in_file_with_path<'a, T>(path: &T) -> Lines<'a, BufferedReader<IoResult<File>>>
        where T: BytesContainer {
    let path = Path::new(path);
    let file = File::open(&path);
    let reader = BufferedReader::new(file);
    reader.lines()
}
```

This gives a compilation error:

```
main.rs:46:5: 46:11 error: `reader` does not live long enough
main.rs:46     reader.lines()
               ^~~~~~
main.rs:42:33: 47:2 note: reference must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the block at 42:32...
main.rs:42         where T: BytesContainer {
main.rs:43     let path = Path::new(path);
main.rs:44     let file = File::open(&path);
main.rs:45     let reader = BufferedReader::new(file);
main.rs:46     reader.lines()
main.rs:47 }
main.rs:42:33: 47:2 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block at 42:32
main.rs:42         where T: BytesContainer {
main.rs:43     let path = Path::new(path);
main.rs:44     let file = File::open(&path);
main.rs:45     let reader = BufferedReader::new(file);
main.rs:46     reader.lines()
main.rs:47 }
error: aborting due to previous error
```

That's because we're trying to return a `Lines` that refers to a `BufferedReader` that ceases to exist when the function returns (the `Lines` would contain a *dangling pointer*).

Now, one might think, “I'll just return the `BufferedReader` along with the `Lines`”.

```
struct LinesInFileIterator<'a> {
    reader: BufferedReader<IoResult<File>>,
    lines: Lines<'a, BufferedReader<IoResult<File>>>
}

impl<'a> Iterator<IoResult<String>> for LinesInFileIterator<'a> {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<IoResult<String>> {
        self.lines.next()
    }
}

fn each_line_in_file_with_path<'a, T>(path: &T) -> LinesInFileIterator<'a>
        where T: BytesContainer {
    let path = Path::new(path);
    let file = File::open(&path);
    let reader = BufferedReader::new(file);
    LinesInFileIterator {
        reader: reader, 
        lines: reader.lines()
    }
}
```

This doesn't work either:

```
main.rs:46:16: 46:22 error: `reader` does not live long enough
main.rs:46         lines: reader.lines()
                          ^~~~~~
main.rs:40:33: 48:2 note: reference must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the block at 40:32...
main.rs:40         where T: BytesContainer {
main.rs:41     let path = Path::new(path);
main.rs:42     let file = File::open(&path);
main.rs:43     let reader = BufferedReader::new(file);
main.rs:44     LinesInFileIterator {
main.rs:45         reader: reader, 
           ...
main.rs:40:33: 48:2 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block at 40:32
main.rs:40         where T: BytesContainer {
main.rs:41     let path = Path::new(path);
main.rs:42     let file = File::open(&path);
main.rs:43     let reader = BufferedReader::new(file);
main.rs:44     LinesInFileIterator {
main.rs:45         reader: reader, 
           ...
main.rs:46:16: 46:22 error: use of moved value: `reader`
main.rs:46         lines: reader.lines()
                          ^~~~~~
main.rs:45:17: 45:23 note: `reader` moved here because it has type `std::io::buffered::BufferedReader<core::result::Result<std::io::fs::File, std::io::IoError>>`, which is non-copyable
main.rs:45         reader: reader, 
                           ^~~~~~
error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

Basically, we can't have a struct that contains a borrowed reference that points to another member of the struct, because when the struct is moved, the reference would become invalid.

There are 2 solutions:

1. Make a function that returns a `BufferedReader` from a file path, and call `.lines()` on it in your `for` loop.
2. Make a function that accepts a closure that receives each line.

   ```
   fn main() {
       for target in os::args().iter() {
           scan_file(target.as_slice());
       }
   }

   fn for_each_line_in_file_with_path_do(path: &str, action: |IoResult<String>|) {
       let path = Path::new(path.as_bytes());
       let file = File::open(&path);
       let mut reader = BufferedReader::new(file);
       for line in reader.lines() {
           action(line);
       }
   }

   fn scan_file(path_str: &str) {
       for_each_line_in_file_with_path_do(path_str, |line| {
           match line {
               Ok(s) => {
                   if s.as_slice().contains("Started ") {
                       print!("{}", s);
                   }
               }
               Err(_) => return,
           }
       });
   }
   ```

Comment: The final code doesn't actually compile. It's fine and I actually tweaked it to work on my computer, but you may want to fix it here! I tried to edit it, but my edit was rejected :-(

Comment: @pablobm: I saw your edit, but it had already been rejected. I edited my answer to incorporate your changes.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to do it without some boilerplate. You need to have *some* source of data, and because iterators return their data in chunks, they either have to contain the data or to have a reference into some other source of this data (this also includes iterators which return data from external source, e.g. lines in a file).

However, because you want to "encapsulate" your iterator into a function call, this iterator cannot be of the second kind, i.e. it cannot contain references, because all references it could contain would point to this function call stack. Consequently, the iterator's source can only be contained in this iterator.

And this is the boilerplate problem - in general there is no such iterator in the standard library. You will need to create it yourself. In this particular case, though, you can get away without implementing `Iterator` trait manually. You only need to create some simple structural wrapper:

```
use std::os;
use std::io::{BufferedReader, File, Lines};

fn main() {
    for target in os::args().iter() {
        scan_file(target.as_slice());
    }
}

struct FileLines {
    source: BufferedReader<File>
}

impl FileLines {
    fn new(path_str: &str) -> FileLines {
        let path = Path::new(path_str.as_bytes());
        let file = File::open(&path).unwrap();
        let reader = BufferedReader::new(file);
        FileLines { source: reader }
    }

    fn lines(&mut self) -> Lines<BufferedReader<File>> {
        self.source.lines()
    }
}

fn scan_file(path_str: &str) {
    for line in FileLines::new(path_str).lines() {
        match line {
            Ok(s) => {
                if s.as_slice().contains("Started ") {
                    print!("{}", s);
                }
            }
            Err(_) => return,
        }
    }
}
```

(I also changed `&String` to `&str` because it is more idiomatic and general)

The `FileLines` structure owns the data and encapsulates all of the complex logic in its constructor. Then its `lines()` method just returns an iterator into its internals. This is rather common pattern in Rust, and usually you will be able to find the main owner of your data and build your program around it with methods which return iterators/references into this owner.

This is not *exactly* what you wanted (there are two function calls in `for` loop initializer - `new()` and `lines()`), but I believe that for all practical purposes they have the same expressiveness and usability.

Comment: Thanks to you too. I had a hard time choosing between the two answers, both were really good and helped me understand Rust a bit better. Sorry I didn't choose yours at the end!